# Scroll bar doesn't appear in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have the following CSS for my site:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, 
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, 
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, 
center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, 
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
html {overflow-y:scroll;}
h1 {
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
}
ul{ list-style-type:none; }
body {
    direction:rtl;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:790px !important;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px auto auto auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;  !important;
}
#page_banner { float:left; }
#content {
    float:right;
    width:790px;
}
.panel_content {
    height:auto;
}
```

And this is the basic structure of my page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page_banner"></div>
    <div id="content" class="panel_content"></div>
<div>
```

The div `content` is dynamic - it's being populated by other divs, according to the data received from a DB. So its height constantly grows. The problem is - when this div is longer that the screen - I see a scrollbar in FF, Opera and even IE. However in Chrome and Safari I don't see it. To make things worse, in Safari I can't even scroll the page with mouse wheel, what I can do in other browsers.
Why is it happening and how can I fix it? I tried to use `overflow-y:scroll;` on the body element - I see the bar appears, but it's disabled, I can't scroll with it.

Comment: just throwing in a quick guess:
try setting
display: inline-block;
on the #wrapper element. this _should_ solve the problem on most of the modern browsers

Comment: @jascha I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't help. The scroll bar didn't appear, and all the #wrapper div, which was centered, shifted to the side.